# Parse information from a website through python

Tags: python, url

I'm trying to read a number from a website into a variable. The source code where the number is looks like this:

```
<tr bgcolor="#ccffff"><td>N_300_0</td><td>5918.720</td></tr>
```

The website will always say N_300_0 but the number will change.

So far I have:

```
link = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.example.com").read()
matches = re.findall('N_300_0', link);
number = ....
```

How do I get the number into the variable?

Comment: Try using beautifulsoup: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web Scraping data using python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562963/web-scraping-data-using-python)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web scraping with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081586/web-scraping-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing any serious or involved scraping, I would strongly agree that something like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a much better way to go.

But to answer your question, you need to use [grouping](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping) in python regex via parens to do the sort of capturing you want, e.g.

```
numbers = re.findall('N_300_0</td><td>([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)',s)
```